# How to get type argument of base type in Mono Cecil as passed by derived type?

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

Consider this hierarchy:

```
class StrDict<T> : Dictionary<string, T> 
class MyDictionary : StrDict<double>
```

I want to get the type `double` using Mono Cecil to replace `T` in the base type name. Ideally, I want to get `StrDict``1`<double>` directly without a workaround.

I tried:

```
var baseTypeDef = ((GenericInstanceType) myDictTypeRef.BaseType).ElementType.Resolve();
var typeParamName = baseTypeDef.GenericParameters.First().FullName
```

But it returned `T`, not `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using the following code ([reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mono-cecil/vtt25K-8tFs)):

```
var genericBaseType = (GenericInstanceType) myDictTypeRef.BaseType;
var genericArgs = genericBaseType .GenericArguments;
var fullBaseTypedName = genericBaseType.ElementType.MakeGenericInstanceType(genericArgs.ToArray()).FullName
```

Which returns `StrDict``1`<double>` as required.